# Natural applications of the Sum-to-Product formulas

Tags: trigonometry, applications

The Sum-to-Product formulas are formulas used to express sums and differences of $\sin$ and $\cos$, for example

$$\cos(p)+\cos(q)=2\cos(\frac{p+q}{2})\cos(\frac{p-q}{2})$$

Are there any good, motivational application of these formulas? All applications I found seem to be quite artificial, like:

1. solve the equation $\sin(5x)+\sin(3x)=0$
2. Compute $\cos(195^o)+\cos(105^o)$.

Since the Sum-to-Product formulas can be proved from the Sum and Difference formulas $\cos(a+b)$ and al., I can solve the second problem by computing $\cos(195^o)$ and $\cos(105^o)$. That's a little bit longer but I would have the satisfaction of knowing the cosine of two new angles, rather than the result of a sum that has been made on purpose. The first one is equivalent to $\sin(3x)=-\sin(5x)$, that one can easily solve without knowing the tricky (is it a $\cos$?  a $\sin$? of $\frac{p+q}{2}$ or of $\frac{p-q}{2}$?) Sum-to-Product formulas.

Why should I learn the Sum-to-Product formulas?

PS: before voting to close because of "too broad" or "asking for a list", please try for a few minutes to find applications or problems that don't seem artificial. You will see that there are not many of them.

Comment: In response to "Why should I learn the Sum-to-Product formulas?" - you shouldn't.  As you have pointed out, they can be proved from the sum and difference formulas; moreover, this proof can be done with five seconds' worth of scribbling in the margin.  Memorising the sum-to-product formulas is a waste of time.  I have been studying and teaching maths for 45 years and I still don't know them.

Comment: I don't really see the point of your question since "artificial" is not a very-well defined term. IMO, the only thing that can be artificial in mathematics is a definition or a theory, but not a result since a result is always interesting (in a broad sense). Why computing $\cos(192°)+\cos(105°)$ would be more artifical than calculating an integral by part?

Comment: @David: I cannot agree more with that comment :). Maybe my question is more "Why should I teach the Sum-to-Product formula?".

Comment: @MoebiusCorzer: (1/2) yes, "artificial" is not well defined. But, I have a motivation to study Integration by parts because it help me to compute much more integrals, and not only *ad hoc *integrals that I will create for the sake of using the formula I just proved. For example, studying Integration by parts helps me to compute $\int \arcsin(x) dx$, or $\int x^ne^{-x}\ dx$. Same thing with the Difference formula $\cos(a-b)=...$ which helps me to increase the number of angles whose trigonometric functions are known, It cannot think of any problem that I wanted to solve before  studying...

Comment: (2/2)... the Sum-to-Product formula, except having a formula for $\sin(a)+\sin(b)$ for the sake of having a new formula and crafting new problems for the next examination. That is what I mean by "artificial".

Comment: IMO: I understand what you mean but I'm just against the idea that we have to find useful ways to use something for this thing to be legitimate. I agree with you that sum-to-product is probably not the fanciest and most useful formula but it appears to be in integration, for example. Then, you will ask why integration is important, etc. and will stop asking when you'll have a concrete application. The thing is that interesting relations can be shown and proved only for the strictly mathematical interest, although mathematics is widely influenced by what it can bring to other fields.

Comment: @MoebiusCorzer: I never said, and never thought, that interest for a mathematical object or formulas, lie in its applications, direct or indirect, to other fields. We can easily compute the values of $\frac{\pi}{3}$ or $\frac{\pi}{4}$ by trigonometric functions, so we may wonder which numbers we can computer values of by trigonometric functions. The Sum and Difference formulas are one formula that partially answers this question. I don't find any motivational question for the Sum-to-Product formula. In other words, why is this formula an "interesting relation"?

Comment: I maybe misunderstood the word "artificial" in your post and it lead me think that you were looking for interesting applications of S-t-P. I agree with you that this formula is not often used, as far as I know. Moreover, we often want to transform a product in a sum (using $\ln$), so you're probably right: the S-t-P formula is maybe artificial, in the sense you meant.

Answer (score 3):

As I have suggested in a comment, don't memorise these formulae.

However, a suggestion as to why they are useful:

> for easily integrating functions of the form $\cos(ax)\cos(bx)$ etc;

which are important because

> they occur in Fourier series;

which are important because

> they are needed to solve partial differential equations involving heat, vibrating strings, vibrating membranes and many many other things.

Comment: That's more a nice application for the Product-to-Sum formulas than the Sum-to-Product ones. But at least, I can sell the S-t-P formulas as an intermediate step towards the P-to-S formulas.